# how change screen led like Cyanogenmod widgetrenderFx night mod

Tags: android, android-widget, render, cyanogenmod, screen-brightness

i work about application how can change android screen brightness, can somme help me by giving some examples of how to doing this.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This peice of code will set the brightness:

```
private void setBrightness(int brightness) {
    try {
        IHardwareService hardware = IHardwareService.Stub.asInterface(
            ServiceManager.getService("hardware"));
        if (hardware != null)
            hardware.setScreenBacklight(brightness);
        } catch (RemoteException doe) {          
    }        
}
```

Do not forget to add to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST" />
```

Please check [this full example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210224163252/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html)

Comment: Hey Sherif, thanks for answer, but i can not download hardwar.jar, where i can find it or the source.

Comment: you do not need to download any jar file. Just add this code and maybe you forgot to add the permission (check the answer I edited it)

Comment: But i have error when import android.os.IHardwareService and import android.os.ServiceManager; and i can't compile

Comment: @user820688 I am sorry... Yes you are right. please check http://code.google.com/p/batterywidget/source/browse/trunk/a_batterywidget/?r=9 ... there is a file called 'hardware09.jar" I hope it has all the classes needed

Comment: Not working , I have test in on android 2.2 , giving me an error " java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.IHardwareService.setScreenBacklight" , I have included the jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android settings for brightness.

```
 android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
                (int)progress);
```

for manualy settings which takes(0-255) as progress and

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putFloat(getContentResolver(),
                AppConstant.SCREEN_AUTO_BRIGHTNESS_ADJ, progress);
```

for automatic settings which takes(-1to 1) as progress