# Set Android setting for Dim screen programmatically

Tags: android

Ho do I set Android system settings to dim after a set period of time.

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.DIM_SCREEN, time);
```

but Settings.System.DIM_SCREEN  is deprecated.I also tried Power Manager PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK which is also deprecated
Any other way around for the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = getWindow().getAttributes();
WMLP.screenBrightness = 0.15F;
getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
```

Comment: i need to change android system setting.

Comment: i hae gone through this link earlier . Here at this link the sol is for brightness i need something for auto dim.Moreover could not download the jar

Comment: at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062305/how-change-screen-led-like-cyanogenmod-widgetrenderfx-night-mod/31176264#31176264) it says this approch not working. Any other way aroud?

Comment: First of all please test this approach and then make any conclusion

Comment: Hi @bpA already tried  but got same problem as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062305/how-change-screen-led-like-cyanogenmod-widgetrenderfx-night-mod/31176264#31176264)